# Payload not handled by any navigator in react navigation 6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am updating my react-native app to use react navigation 6 and I'm trying to figure out how to connect to a screen.

The screen I'm trying to link/navigate to uses a bottomtabnavigator, and looks like this:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

export const PatientScreen = () => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={'Visits'}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Visits" component={VisitsTab} 
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Visits',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="street-view" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Chart" component={ChartTab} 
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Charts',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="id-badge" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Goals" component={GoalsTab} 
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Edit Goals',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="trophy" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I am trying to link to the above from within a screen that is part of a different navigator. That screen looks like this:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Tab, Button } from 'react-native';
import { PatientScreen } from './PatientScreen';

    export const CaseloadScreen = ({navigation}) => {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Caseload</Text>
          <Button title="Patient" 
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('PatientScreen', { screen: 'Visits' })} 
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

When I click on the button above, I get this error:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload undefined was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'PatientScreen'?
```

So clearly I'm missing something, but it's unclear to me what that is. How do I make this `PatientScreen` which uses a bottomTabNavigator, linkable from the button link I listed above?

My navigator for the `Caseload` screen looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { LoginScreen } from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import { CaseloadScreen } from '../screens/CaseloadScreen';
import { WeeklyScreen } from '../screens/WeeklyScreen';
import { ProfileScreen } from '../screens/ProfileScreen';

import { Ionicons, FontAwesome, MaterialCommunityIcons, AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { AvailablePatientScreen } from '../screens/AvailablePatientScreen';

const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} style={{
        activeTintColor: {
          color: '#fff',
        },
      }} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation = () => {
  const icons = {
    tintColor: '#fff',
    size: 20,
  }
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName={'Caseload'}n
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        labelStyle: {
          color: '#fff',
        },
        inactiveTintColor: {
          color: '#fff',
        },
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(61,77,138)',
          width: 240,
          activeTintColor: 'rgb(61,77,138)',
          activeBackgroundColor: '#fff',
          inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: 'rgb(61,77,138)',
        },
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Caseload" component={CaseloadScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<Ionicons name="ios-home" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Weekly Summary" component={WeeklyScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<FontAwesome name="bar-chart" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Available RiverKids" component={AvailablePatientScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<FontAwesome name="child" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="My Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<AntDesign name="profile" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      {/* <Drawer.Screen name="Patient" component={PatientScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<FontAwesome name="bar-chart" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} /> */}
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ title: 'Sign Out', 
        drawerIcon: () => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="logout" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export const Navigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your drawer navigator there is no screen defined with the name 'PatientScreen';

I can see a commented screen in your drawer navigator which has a name Patient and the component is PatientScreen. If you wish to navigate the Patient Screen from the drawer, do uncomment that code and then do the below

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Tab, Button } from 'react-native';

export const CaseloadScreen = ({navigation}) => {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Caseload</Text>
          <Button title="Patient" 
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Patient', { screen: 'Visits' })} 
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Or else if you wish to navigate the PatientScreen only from the Caseload Screen, then create a Stack Navigator with the caseload and patient screen and then in the drawer navigator use that stack navigator in place of caseload screen